# How to differentiate String and Integer in ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, integer

I have array list like this

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add("somethingold");
list.add(3);
list.add("somethingnew");
list.add(5);
```

Now if I print the  list output will be like:

```
[somethingold, 3, somethingnew, 5 ]
```

Here i want to fetch only integer elements.

I want the output like, if it is an integer put it in some other list, else in one more list.

This is what i want:

```
[3,5]
[somethingold, somethingnew]
```

Comment: A bad idea. Use two lists instead and use generics to make them more typesafe.

Comment: You can go for this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html

Comment: or a `List<MyBeanWithAStringAndAnInteger>`. What is the relation between the String and Integer? Do they have to go in the same list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried this?:

```
if(list.get(0) instanceof Integer) {
    // is an integer
} else if (list.get(0) instanceof String) {
    // is a String
}
```

Looping through each element in List

**for loop:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   if (list.get(i) instanceof Integer) {
      // do your stuff
   }
   if (list.get(i) instanceof String) {
      // do your stuff
   }
}
```

**for-each loop:**

```
for (Object obj: list) {
   if (obj instanceof Integer) {
      // do your stuff
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: this is only for first element .what about others??                       and even i tried using for each didnt work                           for (Object object : list) {
   Object varobject.getClass();
   
   
   if(var instanceof String)
   {
    String ne=(String)var;
    str.add(ne);
    
   }
   if(var instanceof Integer){
    Integer ner=(Integer)var;
    in.add(ner);
   }
  }

Comment: Raj just wrap it to loop. and then use list.get(i) element.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `instanceof` operator.

```
        for (Object object : list) 
        {
            if(object instanceof Integer)
            {
                System.out.println(object); // Integer
            }
            else if(object instanceof String)
            {
                System.out.println(object); // String
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

its very simple. Just two lines of code

```
string[] stringList = list.OfType<string>().ToArray();
 Int32[] intList = list.OfType<Int32>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that should create typed Collection like `List<Integer>` or `List<String>` if you are using java 1.5+.

In case of generic array you can use instanceOf operator to differentiate .

```
for(Object obj: list){
   if(obj instanceOf Ineteger){
       ...
   }else if(obj instanceOf String){
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: ok if i take List<String> .but how can i fetch only inttegers from that

Comment: you can not insert `Interger` value to `List<String>` for that you have to create different `List<Ineteger>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch list of objects by using **for-loop**, in that you can find out string and integers.

Below example shows how to get the values..

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
for (Object o : list) {
    if (o.getClass().equals(Integer.TYPE)) {
       ...
    }
    else if (o.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to go over the JDK API , that was one of the most important reason why Generics were introduced in java, to provide you type safe collections.

And you have no need to worry while adding or fetching the elements(no explicit typecasting required).

A friendly suggestion go by the book.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want `[3,5] [somethingold, somethingnew]` which looks already like 2 separate lists.

So you could do

```
class IntegersAndStrings {
    private final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void add(int i) {
        ints.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }

    public void add(String s) {
        strings.add(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ints.toString() + strings.toString();
    }
}
```

and use it like before

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegersAndStrings list = new IntegersAndStrings();
        list.add("somethingold");
        list.add(3);
        list.add("somethingnew");
        list.add(5);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

and the output would be

```
[3, 5][somethingold, somethingnew]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(list);
int index = 0;
for (Object obj: list) {
  index ++;
  if (obj instanceof String) {
     break;
}
}

List<Integer> integerList = list.subList(0.index);
List<String> stringList = list.subList(index,list.size());

System.out.println(integerList);
System.out.println(stringList);
```

Try this, i hope it works

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: Ya got it, `Collections.sort()` might be throwing this exception, as because the list contains both Integer and String.

Answer (score 0):

Using guava library you can do it like this:

```
System.out.println(
     Iterators.toString(Iterators.filter(list.iterator(), String.class)));
System.out.println(
     Iterators.toString(Iterators.filter(list.iterator(), Integer.class)));
```